# Eslint-config-rallycoding installation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Actually I am trying to install `eslint-config-rallycoing` for my react-native project. But it is removing 641 packages after installation can anyone please help me on this?

[image]

Afterwards i am unable to run react-native code.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and also [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for error messages. Use the actual text instead

Answer (score 6):

Try these in this order:

1. `react-native init appName`
2. cd into app folder then run `npm install`
3. `npm install --save-dev eslint-config-rallycoding`
4. `react-native run-android`

Comment: Sometimes npm breaks packages, you can run additional command: yarn install

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this happens when Yarn was used in installing your app's packages during the app's creation (react-native init app_name). So subsequent package installations using npm would cause a lots of packages to be removed.

So in this case you need to install your packages using Yarn. "Yarn add [package name]" You can check out the yarn page for more info https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo - you missed 'd', just type `yarn add eslint-config-rallycoding`